# Acentuação utilizando regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Tenho a seguinte função para normalização de nomes

```
function normalizaNome(nome) {
    var palavras = nome.match(/\b\w+\b/g),
    preps = ["de", "da", "do", "das", "dos"];
        return palavras.map(function(e,i) {
            return preps.indexOf(e) == -1 || i === 0 ? e[0].toUpperCase()+e.slice(1) : e;
    }).join(" ");
}
```

Porém não está aceitando palavras acentuadas.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Character_Classes), o atalho `\w` não considera letras acentuadas.

Um jeito simples de resolver é incluir os caracteres acentuados na regex:

```
var palavras = nome.match(/\b[\wáéíóúâêîôûãõç]+\b/gi);
```

Também coloquei a *flag* `i` para considerar tanto maiúsculas quanto minúsculas, senão a regex teria que ter `áÁéÉ etc...`.

Há também a opção de usar `/\b[\wà-ÿ]+\b/gi`, pois o intervalo `à-ÿ` já contempla vários caracteres acentuados ([veja aqui](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/latin_supplement/list.htm)), porém também vai aceitar alguns caracteres a mais, como por exemplo o [`÷` (DIVISION SIGN)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00f7/index.htm), entre outros que não são letras acentuadas (veja o [link](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/latin_supplement/list.htm) já indicado para ver todos os caracteres).

Vale lembrar que o atalho `\w` também considera dígitos de 0 a 9 e o caractere `_`. Se quer considerar somente letras, bastaria mudar a regex para:

```
/\b[a-záéíóúâêîôûãõç]+\b/gi
```

---

Outra alternativa (**ainda [não compatível com todos os browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Browser_compatibility)**) é usar [*Unicode Property Escapes*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes):

```
var palavras = nome.match(/\b\p{L}+\b/gu);
```

No caso, `\p{L}` são todos os caracteres das categorias "Letter" definidas pelo Unicode (são todas as categorias que começam com "L" [desta lista](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm)). Um detalhe é que a regex precisa da *flag* `u` para que este atalho funcione.

Isso torna a regex um pouco mais abrangente, pois vai considerar letras de outros alfabetos também, como o japonês, árabe, cirílico, etc. Em compensação, ela não considera dígitos e o `_`.

Outra opção para aceitar apenas letras do nosso alfabeto, ignorando outros como o japonês, árabe, etc, é:

```
nome.match(/\b\p{Script=Latin}+\b/gu)
```

Comment: Deu pra entender perfeitamente, obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score -4):

Já tentou algo como

var palavras = nome.match(/(\w+)(\D+)/g);

?

*\w* Todos caracteres gráficos e *\D* todo caractere não dígito (inclusive os acentuados).