# função não executa palavras iguais do regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Tenho uma string qualquer:

```
"novamente mais brevemente uma vez claro, claramente demente, igualmente. novamente."
```

Executo um regex em JavaScript para pegar as palavras terminadas em "mente":

```
var target = $("#content").text();
var exp = /\w+mente/g; // regex ok
var resultado = null;

while (resultado = exp.exec(target)) {
   marcarTexto_adverbio(resultado); // função que coloca uma tag <mark> em volta
};
```

A variável `resultado` passa todos os valores perfeito. Inclusive o "novamente" duplicado no final.

Mas a função que coloca a tag `<mark>` não coloca no segundo "novamente", ou seja não coloca em palavras repetidas:

```
function marcarTexto_adverbio(target) {
    $("#content").html(function (_, html) {
        return html.replace(target, '<mark>' + target + '</mark>')
    });
}
```

Algum erro de lógica na execução dessa função? (já que a array do 'resultados' vai completa, com todas as palavras do regex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiramente, sua regex não busca apenas palavras que terminam em "mente", mas sim qualquer palavra que tenha pelo menos um caractere antes de "mente":

```js
let s = 'seus dementes, a mente engana frequentemente, plante sementes';
console.log(s.match(/\w+mente/g)); // [ "demente", "frequentemente", "semente" ]
```

Veja no exemplo acima que, apesar do texto ter as palavras "dementes" e "sementes", no resultado aparece "demente" e "semente". Ou seja, sua substituição resultaria em `<mark>demente</mark>s` e `<mark>semente</mark>s`, que não é bem o que você precisa.

Isso acontece porque a regex está pegando `\w+` (uma ou mais letras, números ou `_`), seguido de "mente", mas esta regex por si só não garante que não possa ter outra letra depois.

Para evitar isso e só pegar as palavras que de fato terminem em "mente", use o [atalho](https://regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b`, que indica uma [*word boundary*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/420487/112052) ("fronteira entre palavras", uma posição que possui um caractere alfanumérico antes e outro não-alfanumérico depois, ou vice-versa):

```js
let s = 'seus dementes, a mente engana frequentemente, plante sementes';
console.log(s.match(/\b\w+mente\b/g)); // [ "frequentemente" ]
```

A palavra "mente" também não é considerada, pois `\w+` diz que deve ter pelo menos um caractere antes de "mente". Mas se quiser pegar a palavra "mente" também, troque por `\w*`.

---

Outro detalhe é que você está trocando todo o HTML do elemento. Apesar de funcionar em muitos casos, nem sempre será o que você espera, pois [HTML é muito mais complexo do que uma regex é capaz de lidar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454) (veja mais sobre isso [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/129557/112052)).

Tomei a liberdade de adaptar o exemplo da [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/445455/112052) para ilustrar alguns problemas que podem ocorrer:

```js
function marcarTexto_adverbio(target) {
    // mostrando o HTML no console
    $("#content").html(function (_, html) {
        let novoHTML = html.replace(new RegExp(target, "g"), '<mark>' + target + '</mark>');
        console.log(novoHTML);
        return novoHTML;
    });
}

function teste() {
  let target = $("#content").text();
  let exp = /\b\w+mente\b/g;
  let resultado = null;

  let palavrasReplace = new Map();
  while (resultado = exp.exec(target)) {
    const palavra = resultado[0];
    if (!palavrasReplace.has(palavra)) {
      marcarTexto_adverbio(palavra); // função que coloca uma tag <mark> em volta
      palavrasReplace.set(palavra, true);
    }
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="content">novamente
 <a href="www.novamente.com">link</a>
 <img src="novamente.gif" alt="mostra novamente a imagem">
 <span>tem comentário aqui<!-- novamente --></span></p>

<button onclick="teste()">Mark</button>
```

Eu alterei a função `marcarTexto_adverbio` para mostrar o HTML final no console. Repare que o resultado foi:

```html
<mark>novamente</mark>
 <a href="www.<mark>novamente</mark>.com">link</a>
 <img src="<mark>novamente</mark>.gif" alt="mostra <mark>novamente</mark> a imagem">
 <span>tem comentário aqui<!-- <mark>novamente</mark> --></span>
```

Ou seja, tanto o `href` do link, quanto o `src` e o `alt` da imagem, e até o texto que estava nos comentários, tiveram seu conteúdo indevidamente alterado.

Usar regex desta forma, sem se preocupar com a estrutura do HTML do elemento, pode levar a resultados catastróficos. A regex só vai funcionar se dentro do elemento tiver apenas textos simples (ou se uma palavra que ocorre no texto não ocorrer dentro de atributos HTML, nem em qualquer outro lugar que não seja um `textContent`).

A solução para isso é um pouco mais complicada, pois temos que quebrar cada `textNode` em vários nodes, sendo que alguns deles serão elementos `mark`, enquanto outros serão `textNodes`. Por exemplo, o texto "Aconteceu novamente hoje", que no HTML é apenas um `textNode`, terá que ser quebrado em 3 nodes: dois `textNodes` para as palavras "Aconteceu" e "hoje", e um elemento `mark` para "novamente". E caso tenha outra tags dentro do elemento, devo chamar a mesma função recursivamente, para que ela trate os elementos mais internos da mesma.

Ficaria algo assim:

```js
function markWords(element) {
    let e = document.createElement('div');
    for (let child of element.childNodes) {
        if (child.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
            child.nodeValue.split(/(\b\w+mente\b)/g).forEach(s => {
                if (! /^\w+mente$/.test(s)) {
                    e.appendChild(document.createTextNode(s));
                } else {
                    let novo = document.createElement('mark');
                    novo.appendChild(document.createTextNode(s));
                    e.appendChild(novo);
                }
            });
        } else e.appendChild(markWords(child));
    }
    element.innerHTML = e.innerHTML;
    return element;
}

function teste() {
    markWords(document.querySelector('#content'));
    // somente para mostrar o HTML gerado, pode apagar quando for usar na sua página
    console.log(document.querySelector('#content').innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="content">novamente pois novamente o
 <a href="www.novamente.com">link</a>
 <img src="novamente.gif" alt="mostra novamente a imagem">
 <span>tem comentário aqui<!-- novamente --></span>
 <span>antigamente, sementes, demente, novamente</span> <span>e novamente</span> fim.</p>

<button onclick="teste()">Mark</button>
```

O resultado é o HTML correto, com somente as palavras modificadas (preservando corretamente os comentários e atributos HTML):

```html
<mark>novamente</mark> pois <mark>novamente</mark> o
 <a href="www.novamente.com">link</a><img src="novamente.gif" alt="mostra novamente a imagem"><span>tem comentário aqui<!-- novamente --></span><span><mark>antigamente</mark>, sementes, <mark>demente</mark>, <mark>novamente</mark></span><span>e <mark>novamente</mark></span>
```

---

Um último detalhe é que o [atalho](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Character_Classes) `\w` pega letras, dígitos e o caractere `_`. Se quer considerar apenas letras (incluindo os acentos), veja algumas opções [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/443933/112052).

Comment: eu criei um editor de texto num `div` com `contentEditable = True` portanto não terei tags dentro dele. somente texto puro. Tomei o cuidado, inclusive de incluir uma limpeza de caracteres e tags caso o usuário faça 'ctrl+v' com `clipboardData.getData('text/plain')`. E somente nesse `div` eu executo o regex,. Claro, as tags `marks` são inseridas/excluídas com js seguido de `normalize` para corrigir alguns comportamentos de `textNode` que surgiram.

Comment: @LukeNegreiros Tudo bem, de qualquer forma, as respostas do [pt.so] devem servir também para qualquer pessoa que visite o site futuramente, por isso achei interessante mostrar um caso mais geral, pois regex + HTML pode ser uma combinação perigosa se o cenário não for restringido (como é o seu caso)

Answer (score 1):

Existe um problema, o `replace` está efetuando apenas uma substituição da maneira que está sendo utilizado, ao encontrar a primeira ocorrência ele substitui e acabou... Como você tem duas palavras iguais, ele substitui exatamente a mesma palavra duas vezes.

Se você inspecionar o HTML verá que a palavra *novamente* está dentro de duas tags `mark`.

---

Você pode trabalhar com o `replace` utilizando `regex` e a flag *g*, com isso a substituição será efetuada em todas as palavras encontradas.

Sua função `marcarTexto_adverbio` ficaria mais ou menos da seguinte maneira.

```
function marcarTexto_adverbio(target) {
    $("#content").html(function (_, html) {
        return html.replace(new RegExp(target, "g"), '<mark>' + target + '</mark>')
    });
}
```

Isso vai criar as tags `mark` em todas as palavras, porém como existem palavras repetidas, algumas pode ter duas taks `mark` ou até mais.

Para corrigir isso, podemos optar por colocar as palavras já substituídas em um `Map`, veja um exemplo:

```
var palavrasReplace = new Map();

while (resultado = exp.exec(target)) {
  const palavra = resultado[0];

  if (!palavrasReplace.has(palavra)) {
    marcarTexto_adverbio(palavra); // função que coloca uma tag <mark> em volta
    palavrasReplace.set(palavra, true);
  }
};
```

---

Veja o exemplo completo:

```js
function marcarTexto_adverbio(target) {
    $("#content").html(function (_, html) {
        return html.replace(new RegExp(target, "g"), '<mark>' + target + '</mark>')
    });
}

function teste() {
  var target = $("#content").text();
  var exp = /\w+mente/g; // regex ok
  var resultado = null;

  var palavrasReplace = new Map();

  while (resultado = exp.exec(target)) {
    const palavra = resultado[0];

    if (!palavrasReplace.has(palavra)) {
      marcarTexto_adverbio(palavra); // função que coloca uma tag <mark> em volta
      palavrasReplace.set(palavra, true);
    }
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="content">novamente mais brevemente uma vez claro, claramente demente, igualmente. novamente.</p>

<button onclick="teste()">Mark</button>
```

---

> Documentações:
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map