# Qual a maneira correta de buscar e substituir palavras em HTML

Tags: html

Estou refazendo um breve editor de texto no browser. Estou usando uma div editável que contém o seguinte:

```html
<div id="content" class="content_editor" contenteditable="true" onpaste="limpar_formatacao()">
<p>
O meu texto tema a palavra nascer e nascer e também nasceram.
</p> 
<p>
Lorem Ipsum não é simplesmente um texto randômico mas tem nascer no meio.
</p>
</div>
```

Eu preciso de uma função para corrigir o texto marcando com tag `<mark>` todas as palavras **repetidas** de uma frase. Para ficar assim:
(por exemplo, todas as ocorrências da palavra 'nascer')

```html
<p>
O meu texto tema a palavra <mark>nascer</mark> e <mark>nascer</mark> e também nasceram.
</p>
<p>
Lorem Ipsum não é simplesmente um texto randômico mas tem nascer no meio. Uma última frase.
</p>
```

Considerações:

- Reparem que a ***frase*** que não possuir palavra repetida (ou seja, aparecer uma única vez), não é marcada!
- Não dá para pegar por `<p>` porque a separação é por frase, e não por paragrafo.

Então eu fiz uma função para:

- pegar todo o texto
- criar um array de frases:

```js
var textEditor = $("#content").text();
var frases = textEditor.match(/(?! )(.*?(\b\w\w\.))*.*?[.?!](?![.?!])/g);
```

- iniciei array palavras unicas, não-repetidas
- separei por palavra
- um laço p/ cada palavra

  - se maior que 3 letras
  - verifica se existe no array

    - se não: adiciona
    - se sim: marca com o  as duas palavras

Não ficou elegante mas essa função toda ficou assim:

```js
    // ------- algoritmo para repeticao_palavra ------- //
    var textEditor = $("#content").text();
    //separar por frase
    var frases = textEditor.match(/(?! )(.*?(\b\w\w\.))*.*?[.?!](?![.?!])/g);


  frases.forEach((frase) => {
        frase = frase.trimStart(); // limpar o começo de cada frase
        frase = cleanPunctuation(frase); limpar pontuação para não interferir na comparação
        
        var palavras_unicas = []; //iniciar array palavras unicas, não-repetidas
        var palavras = frase.split(' '); //separar por palavra

        //laço p/ cada palavra:
        palavras.forEach((palavra) => {
            palavra = palavra.toLowerCase();
            
            if (palavra.length > 3) { // se maior que 3 letras
                //verificar se existe no array
                if (palavras_unicas.indexOf(palavra) === -1) { //se não: adiciona
                    palavras_unicas.push(palavra);
                }
                else {
                    frase = marcar_palavra_repetida(frase, palavra) //se sim: colocar a tag <mark>
                }
            }
        })
    });
```

A função é `marcar_palavra_repetida()` e ficou assim

```js
function marcar_palavra_repetida(frase, palavra) {

    let str = document.getElementById("content").innerHTML;
    var fraseHTML = frase.replaceAll(palavra, '<mark>' + palavra + '</mark>');

    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = str.replace(frase, fraseHTML);

    return str.replace(frase, fraseHTML); // esse return cria uma recursividade que marca se houver mais de uma palavra repetida na mesma frase
}
```

### Qual a melhor forma de marcar uma palavra em html e marca-la com tags `<mark>`?

- Já me desaconselharam o uso de regex, portanto estou lendo a respeito e considerando apesar da separação em frases estar com regex.
- A função marca corretamente com a tag `<mark>` mas ela pega todas as ocorrências que possuam 'nascer' (como exemplo). Inclusive derivadas ou plural.

ELe marca isso:

```html
<p>
Uma frase com a palavra <mark>nascer</mark> e <mark>nascer</mark> de novo, mas pega também <mark>nascer</mark>am e <mark>nascer</mark>ão na mesma frase.
</p>
```

Comment: quando eu fiz a pergunta eu achei que tinha o minimo verificavel e a lógica do que estou fazendo. já li a política de uso, como usar e por diversas vezes continuo não perguntando direito para a comunidade stackoverflow.

Comment: sim, claro! Editei a pergunta e tentei ser mais correto nas colocações. E sim, a tag mark sofre com adição/retirada de classes e até um a href...

Comment: Não daria pra adaptar a solução [daqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/445450/112052)? Basta incluir uma verificação a mais: se o `match` retorna mais de uma ocorrência vc faz a substituição (desculpe, não parei pra ver mais detalhes da pergunta, mas em uma olhada rápida me parece quase o mesmo problema)

Comment: Seria isso: https://jsfiddle.net/9j3x7fug/1/ ? Claro que falta separar um `p` em várias frases, mas a ideia básica é essa (verificar se a palavra ocorre 2 ou mais vezes na frase).

Comment: @LukeNegreiros, acho que agora eu entendi a pergunta.  A expressão regular é aplicada ao texto dentro de cada parágrafo, havia entendido que seria aplicada um regex para analisar a div toda. Antes de eu publicar uma resposta de uma conferida para ver se esse código soluciona o problema: https://jsfiddle.net/ez9yj1ok/ cc>>@hkotsubo

Comment: @hkotsubo tem uma ocorrência estranha qdo vc clica várias vezes na sua solução publicada no jsfiddle.

Comment: @Augusto Vasques o comportamento é esse mesmo. tentei usar um regex com uma variavel, mas ele não pegava o boundaries. Enfim... vou fazer uns testes mais tarde e ler com mais calma o código. Publica a resposta!

Comment: Agora veja essa variação de texto aplicando a sua solução: https://jsfiddle.net/sqfm1nda/ repare na palavra 'Exército' e ele tira o <br>. Preciso trabalhar nesse codigo ainda.

Comment: O problema é que o `\b` não considera caracteres acentuados, teria que ajustar  assim: https://jsfiddle.net/4x5hjmoa/1/ - quanto ao `<br>`, o link que mandei anteriormente trata desse caso, pois ele mantém as tags filhas. Aí seria o caso de combinar as soluções. Também não ficou claro qual o limite de uma frase. Se tiver duas frases diferentes no mesmo `p`, conta ou não? ex: `<p>Viu tudo? Quase tudo.</p>` <- são 2 frases, então "tudo" está duplicado ou não?

Comment: 'tudo' não estaria duplicado. pois o calculo de duplicação é feita por sentença e não por paragrafo. cheguei num resultado satisfatório, mas como vc disse o \b não pega acentuação. não sabia disso. Putz que saco. Esse regex `new RegExp(`\\b${palavra}\\b`, 'g')` não pega a palavra 'água' por exemplo! mas pega 'exército' (acento no meio)

Comment: Bom, uma alternativa seria `texto.split(/(?<=[.?!])/)` para quebrar o texto em frases, e no replace vc teria que verificar se a palavra já não está dentro de `<mark>` antes de fazer o replace (algo como `/(?<!<mark>)palavra(?!<mark>)/`), pois acho que esse é o problema do meu link. Se bem que ainda acho melhor adaptar o primeiro link que mandei, que mantém a estrutura das tags filhas (o problema é juntar isso com a separação de frases, já que uma mesma frase pode ter várias tags e a palavra duplicada pode aparecer nas tags internas, ou seja, é bem complicado)