# Expressão regular para pegar uma ou mais ocorrências que precedem e sucedem determinada letra

Tags: javascript, regex

Tenho os seguintes casos...

Um primeiro texto da seguinte forma:

```
let text = "olá meu numero é trezentos e vinte e quatro tudo bem?"
```

E este texto quer recebo também pode ser como exemplo:

```
let text = "olá meu número é quarenta e três tudo bem?
```

Tentei fazer uma expressão regular que pega as ocorrências antes e depois do `e` para pegar as palavras que tem antes e depois do `e`. Fiz da seguinte forma:

```
console.log(text.match(/(\w+\se\s\w+)/g))
```

Porém a saída que tenho no primeiro caso de texto é `'trezentos e vinte'`, de modo que *ignora* o segundo grupo do `e`. Eu gostaria que a saída nesse caso fosse `'trezentos e vinte e quatro'` e se eu passasse o segundo texto fosse `'quarenta e três'` a saída mesmo, mas estou com muita dificuldade com essa Regex, poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: Se a frase mudar para `"olá eu e ela temos o numero é trezentos e vinte e quatro tudo bem?"` vai dar problema.

Comment: Estou upando as resposta, mas acho que o problema é bem maior que regex é NLP.

Comment: Bem colocado augusto, dei uma pesquisada agora em nlp e existe algumas bibliotecas em node que fazem diversas tratativas pelo que entendi né? vou me aprofundar um pouco mais no assunto, muito obrigado!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [Conforme apontado nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/500347/express%C3%A3o-regular-para-pegar-uma-ou-mais-ocorr%C3%AAncias-que-precedem-e-antecedem-de/500354?noredirect=1#comment926289_500347), a solução abaixo vai trazer falsos positivos se a frase tiver quaisquer palavras que não sejam números e tenham um "e" entre elas. Então veja se é isso mesmo que você precisa...

---

Primeiramente, o atalho `\w` não pega caracteres acentuados, então sua regex não funciona nem para "quarenta e três":

```js
let text = "olá meu número é quarenta e três tudo bem?";
console.log(text.match(/(\w+\se\s\w+)/g)); // [ 'quarenta e tr' ]
```

Para isso você pode usar a *flag* `u` ([veja aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/499630/112052) para mais detalhes), ou colocar os acentos na regex. E para repetir a parte "e ....", basta colocar outro [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) em volta dele:

```js
let text = "olá meu número é trezentos e quarenta e três tudo bem?";

// com a flag "u" e Unicode Properties
console.log(text.match(/\p{L}+( e \p{L}+)+/ug)); // [ 'trezentos e quarenta e três' ]

// colocando os acentos na regex
console.log(text.match(/[a-záéíóúâêôãõ]+( e [a-záéíóúâêôãõ]+)+/ig)); // [ 'trezentos e quarenta e três' ]
```

Com a *flag* `u`, usei [Unicode Properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes) (no caso, `\p{L}` pega qualquer letra definida pelo Unicode - que são os que estão nas categorias que começam com "L" [desta lista](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm)). Outro detalhe é que isso também acaba sendo abrangente demais, pegando letras de outros alfabetos (japonês, árabe, etc). Se quiser restringir para o nosso alfabeto, pode trocar `\p{L}` por `\p{Script=Latin}`.

No segundo caso, coloquei as letras acentuadas na regex. Só coloquei minúsculas, mas usei a *flag* `i`, então ela também vai considerar as letras maiúsculas. Esta é uma alternativa caso o seu ambiente ainda não suporte Unicode Properties.

E na parte que tem " e etc...", coloquei outro quantificador em volta - no caso, `+`, pois entendi que essa parte se repete uma ou mais vezes. E troquei `\s` por um espaço simples (já que `\s` também pega quebras de linha e [outros caracteres](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/405703/112052)).

Além disso, tem outra diferença: o `\w` pega também os dígitos de 0 a 9 e o caractere `_`. Já as regex que fiz acima só pegam letras (o que parece fazer mais sentido no seu caso).

---

Sobre regex e acentos, ver também [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/406366/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/443938/112052).

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, não tenho muito conhecimento em regex então estava perdido, mas você me salvou, obrigado demais!

Answer (score 3):

Isso acontece porque a expressão regular desconsidera que sequências de `e` podem vir uma após a outra.

Desse modo, embora isto funcione:

```
/(\w+\se\s\w+)/g

foo aaa e bbb bar baz ccc e ddd qux
```

Isto não funcionaria:

```
/(\w+\se\s\w+)/g

foo aaa e bbb e ccc qux
```

Porque a expressão regular `/(\w+\se\s\w+)/g` não determina o *match* de duas sequências seguidas uma da outra. Isso porque  ela exige termos **antes** e **depois** do `e`. No caso de já ter dado *match* numa expressão imediatamente anterior ao próximo `e`, não terá nada "antes" dele, de modo que o *match* será impossível por não satisfazer essa condição.

Uma solução é indicar que qualquer termo *após* o `e` pode se repetir dentro de um único *match*. Uma opção seria assim:

```
/\w+(?:\se\s\w+)+/g

foo aaa e bbb bar baz ccc e ddd e eee qux
```

<sup>Veja no [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/QodGli/1/).</sup>

Embora a expressão regular acima funcione para casos em que as palavras forem formadas por caracteres alfanuméricos ASCII, letras acentuadas (como `é`, `á`, `à` etc) não são englobadas pelo `\w`.

Desse modo, você pode mudar a expressão para:

```
/\p{L}+(?:\se\s\p{L}+)+/gu

foo aáà e bbb bar baz ccc e ddd e eéè qux
```

<sup>Veja no [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/QodGli/2/).</sup>

De modo que, ao utilizar a *flag* `u`, pode-se utilizar `\p{L}`, que captura qualquer letra definida pelo padrão Unicode – o que inclui os caracteres acentuados anteriormente mencionados.

Apesar de já ser bem suportado, alguns ambientes podem não implementar expressões regulares com a *flag* do Unicode. Nesses casos, para alternativas ao `\p{L}` com a *flag* `u`, consultar a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/500355/69296).

---

<sup>Não relacionado à resposta, mas vale observar que a expressão regular *original* da pergunta (`/(\w+\se\s\w+)/g`) poderia ser substituída por `/\w+\se\s\w+/g`, uma vez que o grupo de captura nesse caso não faz nada.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Nesse caso o que você precisa é usar `(\w+\se\s\w+)` como um grupo e colocar um quantificador. Veja:

```js
let text1 = "olá meu numero é trezentos e vinte e quatro tudo bem?";
let text2= "olá meu número é quarenta e três tudo bem?"

console.log(text1.match(/\w+(\se\s[a-zê]+)+/g))
console.log(text2.match(/\w+(\se\s[a-zê]+)+/g))
```

Comment: ah ok. Eu tinha colocado `[a-zê]` justamente para pegar esse caso. Mas sua solução é bem mais geral. Obrigado pelos toques.

Comment: Ok. Editei a resposta